# grails, error after the application has runned sussesfully, red exclamation mark on my project?

Tags: grails

I'm new to grails, I'm having an issue when I run my grails application.The console displays errors that is shown below. Although it is working fine in my application it is getting on my nerves to see the errors every time I run the application. And also I have red exclamation mark on my project, what is it?

Can any one tell me how to fix it?

```
 Error 2013-09-16 11:13:40,270 [http-bio-8333-exec-2] ERROR [/hubbub].[gsp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/hubbub] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

| Error 2013-09-16 11:13:49,467 [http-bio-8333-exec-8] ERROR [/hubbub].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/hubbub] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

Hibernate: select this_.id as id2_0_, this_.version as version2_0_, this_.date_created as date3_2_0_, this_.password as password2_0_, this_.profile_id as profile5_2_0_, this_.user_id as user6_2_0_ from user this_ limit ?
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from user this_
| Error 2013-09-16 11:13:59,475 [http-bio-8333-exec-9] ERROR [/hubbub].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/hubbub] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run mentioned 4 commands on your grails command line one by one 1)refresh-dependencies 2)clean 3)compile 4)run-app

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work. I tried to see the problem in window>Show View>problems and I see that the version between my project and my workspace is not the same. I think that's the case for the Red Exclamation mark be on my project icon. But the error that I specified earlies is still there after running my application.

Comment: Try to upgrade your project, For upgrading go through http://pledbrook.github.io/grails-howtos/en/upgradeToGrails2.html

Comment: I tried to upgrade my project but the error stil there here is the error.  Groovy: compiler mismatch Project level is: 1.8 Workspace level is 2.0 Groovy compiler level expected by the project does not match workspace compiler level.  Go to Project properties -> Groovy compiler to set the Groovy compiler level for this project

Comment: Go to Preferences->Groovy->Compiler->switch to 1.8.6.xx click on this button. I hope your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `<g:script/>` to `<script/>` type tag in your view.gsp and all is well,
I recently fixed that type of issue myself.